# Как изменить формат координат в js?

Tags: яндекс-карты, yandex-maps-jsapi

У меня переставлены местами longtitude и latitude, поэтому при попытке что-то закинуть в яндекс карту точки находятся где попало. Можно ли как-то заставить его использовать другой синтаксис?

Comment: Можно "переставить" правильно, потом уже "закидывать".

Comment: Что значит закидывать? Вроде бы везде в АПИ идет указание широты и долготы как отдельных чисел.

Comment: В ответе уже подсказали по поводу JS API 2.1. Но следует заметить, что в API 3.0 нет этого параметра. Там менять порядок координат только заранее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если речь идёт о **JS API Яндекс Карт** [версии 2.1](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/), то порядок координат выбирается параметром [coordorder](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/v2-1/dg/concepts/load#param:%7E:text=Suggest%20API%3E.-,coordorder,-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85) подключения API. Возможные значения: **latlong** — [широта, долгота] — используется по умолчанию; **longlat** — [долгота, широта].

Пример "[Добавления на карту GeoJSON файла из Конструктора карт](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_geojson)" песочницы Яндекс наглядно демонстрирует работу параметра.